# How to set a button's image background in cs and keep it showing while disabled?

Tags: c#, uwp

I was just wondering if there would be a way to change the Image background of a button using cs and then keep it the same when disabled as when it is enabled and when switching between the two states, Thanks.

```cs
bt1.Background = "/Assets/Image1.png";
bt1.IsEnabled = false;
// at this point the background of button becomes invisible
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Here is the 3 step approach for adding an image to button in Windows UWP:**

```
// Step 1: Create an image object
Image img = new Image();
img.Source = new BitmapImage(new Uri(@"Assets\Image1.png"));


// Step 2: Add the image to a stack panel
StackPanel sp = new StackPanel();
sp.Children.Add(buttonImage);
// Add other items to stack panel


// Step 3: Set the stack panel as the button content
Button btn = new Button();
btn.Content = sp;
```

Comment: Hi, thanks for the input, I'm fairly new to this so this might be a mistake on my part but to clarify I'm using UWP so that might be it. But when i tried this it tells me that "Button" does not contain a definition for "Image". Would there be a way to fix this?

Comment: Hi, I updated the answer with code for UWP. Thanks for the input.

Answer (score 0):

I've never really worked with styling in C # and don't know if you use CSS for the styling. But if so you could probably use something like this in your css file

```
button {
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
}

button:hover {
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
}

button:disabled,
button[disabled]{
  background-image: url("paper.gif");
}
```